# App Doesn't Install on iOS 8 (App Store)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, app-store

I have an app titled Code4Armour that is LIVE on the App Store. It requires a minimum iOS version of 7.0. I have successfully installed it on devices running 7.0 and 7.1 as well as devices running any iOS version greater then 8.0. Weird thing is that my coworker tried installing it on her iPhone 5S running iOS 8.0 and it doesn't let her install it, giving a error message "This app requires iOS 8.0.1" (something like that)..how is this possible, when I've installed it on devices running iOS 7?

Any help would be greatly appreciated..is this a bug on Apple's end?

**UPDATE**

I've attached 2 screenshots of the error message within the App Store below. Notice how it says the app requires an updated iOS version, but the minimum requirement of the app is iOS 7..

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would confirm this yourself by testing a clean install on an iOS 8 device and on an iOS 7 device at the same time. Then I would call Apple if there really is an error message or log a bug via https://bugreport.apple.com .

Comment: @RoboticCat do you mean doing a clean install via xCode?

Comment: @MikeSimz, can you get a screen shot of error message from your co-worker and add it the question?

Comment: @BlackFrog I've added screen shots

Comment: This is a bug. File a radar.

Comment: @dasdom where at..bugreport.apple.com?

Comment: It looks like a bug to me unless Apple's implemented some sort of minimum iOS 8 version level? Basically I would file a bug and wait for Apple's response. But I would also test on installing via Xcode and on an iOS 8.0.1 device (or later version) to see if you get a more helpful error message.

Comment: @RoboticCat I've tried via xCode and installed successfully on every version of iOS 8. No errors, no warnings, nothing..

Comment: @MikeSimz Yes, bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to ios 8.01?

Comment: @logixologist I have not tried updating this specific device to 8.0.1, but I have installed successfully on other devices running 8.0.1. The issue here is that it won't install on 8.0..this needs to be fixed. I've filed a bug. Hopefully I hear from Apple soon!

Comment: I wonder if they are not supporting that version on ios 8.0. Remember they had done a failed release with 8.0.1 and ended up having to release a new one to fix it. 8.0.1 would actually disable your phone.

Comment: This may be a bug in 8.0.0 OR Apple is refusing to allow some types of apps to install on that specific version due to a bug. You can't fix 8.0.0 if that's where the problem lies. I doubt anything can be done.